# Splitting an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I have an array like

```
@tmp = ('value1-1', 'value1-2', 'value1-3', '', 'value2-1', 'value2-2', 'value2-3')
```

How do I split the array into two parts after seeing that the value is empty `''`?

So that the output should be like this

```
@value1=('value1-1','value1-2','value1-3');
@value2=('value2-1','value2-2','value2-3');
```

I've tried this way

```
foreach $item(@tmp){
    unless($add == ''){
         #print $add;
         push (@value,$add);
    }
}
```

it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I see 2 problems with your example. 1. Your iterator variable is `$item` but you're pushing a different variable `$add` onto the array. 2. Yo're only pushing onto one array. You can't push onto one array and expect the values to go to 2 arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop through the list while using an array reference to decide which target array you're populating.

```
my @value1;
my @value2;

my @tmp = ('value1-1', 'value1-2', 'value1-3', '', 'value2-1', 'value2-2', 'value2-3');

my $target = \@value1;
for my $val ( @tmp ) {
    if ( $val eq '' ) {
        $target = \@value2;
    }
    else {
        push( @{$target}, $val );
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat, but moving one element at a time is very slow.

Comment: I don't see that being a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to search for the first blank element. You can do it conveniently using the `firstidx` function from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'firstidx';

my @tmp = ('value1-1', 'value1-2', 'value1-3', '', 'value2-1', 'value2-2', 'value2-3');

my $i = firstidx { length == 0 } @tmp;
my @value2 = @tmp;
my @value1 = splice @value2, 0, $i;
shift @value2;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@value1, \@value2;
```

**output**

```
(
  ["value1-1", "value1-2", "value1-3"],
  ["value2-1", "value2-2", "value2-3"],
)
```

The module isn't a core module so you may prefer not to install it. You can write your own helper function with

```
sub first_blank_idx {
  my ($arr) = @_;
  length $arr->[$_] or return $_ for 0 .. $#$arr;
  return -1;
}
```

and change the call to `firstidx` to `my $i = first_blank_idx(\@tmp)`

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tmp = ('value1-1', 'value1-2', 'value1-3', '', 'value2-1', 'value2-2', 'value2-3');

my @blanks = grep {$tmp[$_] eq ''} 0 .. $#tmp;

die "No blank elements" unless @blanks;
warn "More than one blank" if @blanks > 1;

my @value1 = @tmp[0 .. $blanks[0]-1];
my @value2 = @tmp[$blank[0]+1 .. $#tmp];

use Data::Dump;
dd \@value1, \@value2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `part` from [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) to partition an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw(part);

my @array = (
    'foo', 'bar', 'baz', '',
    'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', '',
    'apple', 'pear', 'banana'
);

my $index = 1;
my @parts = part { $_ eq '' ? $index++ && 0 : $index } @array;

print Dumper \@parts;
```

#### Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '',
            ''
          ],
          [
            'foo',
            'bar',
            'baz'
          ],
          [
            'alpha',
            'beta',
            'gamma'
          ],
          [
            'apple',
            'pear',
            'banana'
          ]
        ];
```

As you can see from the example, this will work for any number of partitions, not just two. The results are stored in an array of arrays, with the empty records (`''`), stored in `$array[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split` and `join` to do that pretty concisely:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my @tmp = 
   ('value1-1', 'value1-2', 'value1-3', '', 'value2-1', 'value2-2', 'value2-3');

# note that since the pivot value is empty there with be two && in its place
# we can split on that
my ($values1, $values2) = 
   map { [split '&', $_] } split('&&', join('&', @tmp));

__END__
[
   'value1-1',
   'value1-2',
   'value1-3'
],
[
   'value2-1',
   'value2-2',
   'value2-3'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As *Andy Lester* points out in his comment, an item-by-item filtering of the original `@tmp` array is probably fast enough unless the array is huge.

If the Perl 5 installation is version 14 or later then `push` accepts an array *reference* as its first parameter, so the switch between arrays can be written neatly using a state variable like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my @tmp = ('value1-1', 'value1-2', 'value1-3', '', 'value2-1', 'value2-2', 'value2-3');

my (@value1, @value2);
my $split;

for (@tmp) {
  if (length or $split) {
    push $split ? \@value2 : \@value1, $_;
  }
  else {
    $split = 1;
  }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \(@value1, @value2);
```

**output**

```
(
  ["value1-1", "value1-2", "value1-3"],
  ["value2-1", "value2-2", "value2-3"],
)
```

On earlier versions the array must be dereferenced, so the `push` call would become

```
push @{ $split ? \@value2 : \@value1 }, $_;
```